# How can an ultrapower of a model of ZFC be "ill-founded" yet still satisfy ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, ultrafilters

My understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong) is that if you have some transitive set M which is an $\epsilon$-model of ZFC, and you take an ultrapower of it using an approprate ultrafilter, you wind up with a new model whose membership relation is not the $\epsilon$ relation of the ambient set theory, but still satisfies ZFC.  Furthermore, if the membership relation of the ultrapower is well-founded, one can always use the Mostowski collapse theorem to produce an isomorphic $\epsilon$-model.

My question is this: how could one possibly end up with a model of ZFC which satisfies the axiom of regularity ("every set is disjoint from one of its members"), yet whose membership relation *isn't* well-founded?

I'm struggling to imagine this; the most I can come up with is that for no set in the infinite chain is its transitive closure also a set (of the model).  But I'm skeptical about whether or not that can be the case, because it seems like you ought to be able to construct the transitive closure using definition by transfinite recursion, letting $f(0)$ be any set in the chain and $f(n+1)=\bigcup f(n)$ (axiom of union).  Then $f(\omega)$ (axiom of infinity) ought to contain all the sets needed to build a contradiction to regularity.

Sorry if this question sounds like I'm arguing with myself.  This has been bothering me for a few days now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For an ultrapower of $V$ by an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ there is an exact characterization of when the ultrapower will be well-founded: precisely when $\mathcal{U}$ is closed under countable intersections.

As for how a model $M$ could possibly satisfy regularity but not be wellfounded, the problem is that there may be infinite descending chains that $M$ cannot 'see': each individual object may belong to $M$ but the chain itself may not. I can be a little more precise. Let's say $R$ is what $M$ understands to be the $\in$-relation. There may well be $x_0,\ldots x_n,\ldots $ belonging to $M$ so that $x_{n+1}Rx_n$ for all $n\in\omega$; as long as the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ does not belong to $M$ the axiom of regularity from $M$'s point of view need not be violated.

You don't need ultrapowers to construct such models. Assuming CON(ZFC) you can build one using the compactness theorem for first order logic.

Comment: Thanks Justin!  But, as I mentioned in my question, if all the sets of the chain are sets of the model, and the model has an infinite ordinal (whose image under the membership relation of the model will necessarily be infinite, since [in]finiteness is absolute), then the sequence must also belong to the model by the axiom of replacement.  

Comment: Not true; just because $x_0,x_1...x_n...$ all belong to a model there is no reason to believe the set containing them all belongs to the model. (Otherwise a model should contain all its countable subsets, and then how could we have countable models of ZFC?)

Look at what you are saying more formally and try to see where it breaks down. What set and formula are you attempting to apply replacement to?

Comment: Well, every model contains all of its **definable** countable subsets (like "all natural numbers except 52").  I thought that "$\bigcup x$" was definable from "$x$", and that definition by transfinite recursion of a definable relation was acceptable.  Clearly some part of that is untrue, but I'm trying to figure out which part.

Comment: Transitive closure is definable, and if say x is the first element of the chain  then indeed tc(x) (or more precisely what M believes to be the transitive closure) will belong to M. But even with the entire chain a subset of tc(x), that still won't violate regularity inside M, because the chain itself need not belong to M.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Now I get it.  There is a set in the model of which the chain is a subset (I was having a very hard time believing otherwise).  The issue is that you don't get a contradiction with regularity until you have arranged the illfounded sequence into a chain ($f:\omega\to X$ where $(\forall n)f(n+1)\in f(n)$, and this last part is what you aren't able to do in the internal language of the illfounded model.  Thanks Justin!

Comment: (because I took the time to type this up:) For the formula, use Theorem 2 of http://planetmath.org/?method=l2h&from=objects&name=TransfiniteRecursion&op=getobj and let A be $\omega$ and let $\phi(f,y)$ be $y=x\cup\bigcup\text{ran}(f)$; it is a theorem of ZFC that $(\exists f)(\forall s<A)f(s)=x\cup\bigcup\text{ran}(f|^{<s})$. So $f(0)=x$ and $f(n+1)=\bigcup f(n)$. Now apply the axiom of replacement using $f$ to $\omega$, and the result ought to be the transitive closure of $x$, no?

Comment: The ill-founded model has a fake omega, a nonstandard omega with nonstandard natural numbers, that look infinite from the outside, but which the model believes to be finite. It can produce what it thinks is a finite descending sequence properly extending the actual descending epsilon sequence, but this still doesn't violate Foundation because it would need an infinite sequence using its own omega for a counterexample.

Comment: Oh wow, that adds a whole new dimension to this.  Let me see if I understand correctly.  Do you mind if I speak in terms of ordinals rather than naturals?  If I understand you correctly, the least ordinal ($\omega$) which the model believes to be infinite actually has predecessors which in turn have infinitely many predecessors -- but the model does not believe they have infinitely many predecessors.  Did I get that right?  By the way, is there a book that explains this phenomenon?  I've seen nonstandard naturals before, but never encountered nonstandard ordinals in models of ZFC.

Comment: ... had to break this up due to the character limit on comments.  So, if I haven't gone off track yet, there is a function $f:\lambda\to X$ where $\lambda<\omega$ and $(\forall n)f(n+1)\in f(n)$.  The ordinal $\lambda$ is actually infinite from the outside, but the model thinks that it is a "non-infinite" ordinal (which I guess makes it "finite").  Wild stuff.

Comment: Oh, and this also explains how the model might also believe "for every set there exists some ordinal $\lambda$ such that the set is in $V_\lambda$".  That was the other thing that was nagging me.  So I guess in this case $\lambda$ is an ill-founded ordinal.

Comment: Yes, I believe you've got it!

Comment: For ultrapowers of the universe, you can prove that they are ill-founded if and only if they have an ill-founded omega. This is because both of these are equivalent to the countable incompleteness of the ultrafilter. The ill-foundedness, if it exists at all, must exist already in the natural numbers. But for other nonstandard models of set theory, which are not obtained by ultrapowers, the ill-foundedness can begin much higher up.

Comment: Perhaps this is an inappropriate suggestion for this particular question, but why not just append ZFC with some sort of second-order axiom which asserts well-foundedness? Is this equivalent to a full second-order axiom system of ZFC? My worry is that there is an unnecessary focus on the first-order aspects of ZFC; why shouldn't we adopt a fragment of second-order ZFC as some sort of foundation in general?


Comment: That is what we often (implicitly) do.  Rather than talking about arbitrary models of set theory (ZFC), we talk about transitive $\in$-models, which up to isomorphism are the same as well-founded models.  --- However, this concerns only set theory itself; in mathematics outside set theory, already full first order ZFC is usually more than needed, and there is (usually, or at least often) no need to consider second order extensions.